# how to set value in form in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have data I want to populate in a form. I am using reactive form in Angular 6.

**Demo Application**

I have list of items in which there is `edit` button .On click of `edit` button I am showing `edit component`

I want to populate or set all values in input field. I have data in an obj now I want to populate that in form

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkf4wa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.ts

**on Edit component**

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.product$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getSelectedProduct))
  //       .subscribe((res)=>{
  //    console.log('ssssss');
  // console.log(res)
  //       },()=>{
  //         console.log('dddd')
  //       })
}
```

**Edit button click**

```js
editProduct(product: Product, item) {
  const editProduct: EditProductInterface = {
    product: product,
    selectedIndex: item
  }
  this.store.dispatch(new productActions.EditProduct(editProduct));
  this.router.navigate(['edit'])
}
```

Comment: downvoter please tell what is the wrong in this Question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `patchValue` to set the formControlValue

```
   this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getSelectedProduct))
        .subscribe((res)=>{
          console.log('ssss'+res.productName)
          this.productForm.patchValue({
            productName: res.productName, 
            starRating: res.starRating, 
            productCode: res.productCode, 
            description: res.description, 
            id: res.id
          });
        },()=>{
          console.log('dddd')
        })
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1xuxm?file=src/app/edit/edit.component.ts)

Comment: ` this.product$ =  this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getSelectedProduct))`

Comment: instead of `subscribe` is there any other way

Comment: you need to subscribe in order to access the data

Comment: when i am using `async` pipe i don't need to unsubscribe the this that why I am saying

Comment: well, when you exit the component observable gonna do that for u. but your component is staying for than usually then yes u can unsubscribe.

Answer (score 6):

In angular, there are two methods, **setValue** and **patchValue** using these two methods you can set value in your form's controls.
When you have the requirement to fill all the form control with data then use **setValue** method and when you have the requirement to fill only specific form control with data then use **patchValue** method.
Below is the code example I hope this will help you.

**userForm:FormGroup;**

**//Use below code example when you need to fill data in all the controls of form.

```
this.userForm.setValue({
    firstName:'test first name',
    lastName:'test last name',
    email:'test@test.test'
});
```

**//Use below code example when you need to fill data only in the specific form control

```
this.userForm.patchValue({
    firstName:'test first name',
    lastName:'test last name'
});
```

In the above two methods, I have used firstName, lastName and email property, these property name needs to be same as of your **formControlName** name given in HTML markup.

Official documentation of setValue and patchValue method are available [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

Answer (score 1):

use `patchValue` for this.

```
this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getSelectedProduct)).subscribe((res) => {
    this.productForm.patchValue(res);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name"
                required ngModel #name="ngModel">
```

or this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{product.name}}"
                required ngModel #name="ngModel">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `patchValue` if in case you need to update only certain fields. If you plan to update all fields, you may also use `setValue` as suggested below.

```
    this.productForm.patchValue({
      productName: res.productName,
      id: res.id
    });

    this.productForm.setValue({
      productName: res.productName,
      id: res.id,
      starRating: res.starRating,
      productCode: res.productCode,
      description: res.description,
    });
```